# Trying to move player inventories in FTB Infinity Evolved

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Soo, a few weeks into our gameplay in this modpack we discovered a corrupted chunk, and now its unbearable to play in the server as of lag. After some testing we realized that the world itself was causing the lag. We sought out to change worlds, but wanted to keep our thaumcraft research and inventories. Ive tried moving the player.dat files but our inventories didnt move over. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, after like 5 minutes of screwing around after posting this I got it to work, for those who are having this issue, i just realized you need to copy the level.dat over aswell!